# Printing localStorage values to the HTML page

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, local-storage

Right now I have 5 values stored into an array, and the array is stored into localStorage.

I have a function that takes 3 arguements. The array, the key name, and a callback function that parses the array in local storage.

I also have the callback function itself which just parses the array in local storage.

Then I have a function that is supposed to render each array item to the page using a forEach function, however I am not sure what to put into the actual forEach function itself. I've tried passing in things like the key, I have been stuck on this for days, and although I have learned along the way, I am still stuck in wanting to print the stored data to the actual page.

Here is a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/monanoruno/edit?html,css,js,output

My code is here:

```
window.onload = function() {
//global variables (global scope)
  var warning = document.getElementById('warning');

  var clear = document.getElementById('clear')

//array used for localstorage
  var listItemArray = [];
  var key = 'todos';

//this is where the party starts
  fetch('todos', render);
  clear.addEventListener('click', clearInput, false);

};
// create a function that adds task on user click button
function addTask() {
  //variables within addTask scope
  var addLi = document.createElement('LI');
  var deleteTask = document.createElement('input');
  var input = document.getElementById('userTask');
  var inputValue = document.createTextNode(input.value);
  var myUL = document.getElementById('myUL');

  validate(input)  //returns input or false

  //define attributes of delete task button
  deleteTask.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
  deleteTask.setAttribute('value', 'X');
  deleteTask.setAttribute('id', 'delete');
  //event listener that toggles a 'crossout' effect for completed tasks
  addLi.addEventListener('click', taskToggle, false);
 //add the input value and delte task elements to the list item
  addLi.appendChild(inputValue);
  addLi.appendChild(deleteTask);
 //add list element to ul element
  myUL.appendChild(addLi);
  //add the list item to an array
  listItemArray.push(input.value);
 //event that deletes single tasks
  deleteTask.addEventListener('click', function(){
    myUL.removeChild(addLi);
  });

}

function validate(input) {
  return input.value.length ? input : false
}

function storeListItems(listItemArray, key, fetch) {
  var notes = JSON.stringify(listItemArray);
  fetch(localStorage.setItem(key, notes));
}

function fetch(key, callback) {
  callback(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)));
}

function render(data) {
  data.forEach(function (current, index, array) {

  });
}




//define clear button
function clearInput() {
  var input = document.getElementById('userTask');
  input.value = '';
}

//function removes all list elements created
function removeAll(myUL) {
  //try while(myUL.firstChild) myUL.firstChild.remove()
  myUL.innerHTML = '';
}

//define crossout function
function taskToggle(e) {
//li elements are targetted by the event object
  var li = e.target;
//if li contains class remove, else add
  if (li.classList.contains('crossOut')) {
    li.classList.remove('crossOut');
  } else {
    li.classList.add('crossOut');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update `listItemArray` and `localStorage` while adding item.

```
function addTask() {
    var input = document.getElementById('userTask');
    if (validate(input)) {
        listItemArray.push(input.value);
        storeListItems(listItemArray, 'todos');
        renderHtml(input.value);
    }
}
```

fetch the `todos` onload and render them

```
function fetch(key, callback) {
    listItemArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    callback(listItemArray);
}
```

update `listItemArray` and `localStorage` after removing an item

```
deleteTask.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var index = listItemArray.indexOf(val);
    listItemArray.splice(index, 1);
    storeListItems(listItemArray, 'todos');
    myUL.removeChild(addLi);
});
```

empty the list on `remove all`

```
function removeAll(myUL) {
    myUL.innerHTML = '';
    listItemArray = [];
    storeListItems(listItemArray, 'todos');
}
```

check this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/qaruyeziya/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Just a few questions: 1. Where does the val parameter for the RenderHTML function and inputValue createElement come from? Is it just a placeholder thing? 2. My remove all button doesn't work. It works if I make an alert inside the removeAll function but setting the UL's innerHTML to an empty string doesnt seem to do anything anymore.

Comment: 1. (a) `val` - on page load, we get todo items from `localStorage`, if there any, and render them using `renderHtml` function so here `val` refers to each todo item. (b) while adding a todo item `val` is the value(text) entered by user. 2. please check the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qaruyeziya/edit?js,output) now

Comment: Makes total sense! You taught me a lot with your answers, now my goal is to learn more about callbacks and whatnot. I also think I am going to sort of make a mini localStorage interface that I can implement into future projects with what i've learned from this app. Cheers mate!

Comment: @Laere I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code so that it saves whatever is currently in the `listItemArray` to local storage, and then prints each item in that persistently-stored array back out again once the page is loaded.

Turns out you weren't ever actually saving the array to local storage, and as a result you were getting null every time your `render()` function was called.

You will notice that I have now added this line: `storeListItems(listItemArray, 'todos');` which is now correctly storing the array (converted to a string first) into local storage via the `todos` key.

Your definition for the anonymous function inside the `data.forEach` loop was specifying too many parameters. You will notice that it now only specifies a single parameter, which represents the current item being accessed as part of  the loop iteration:

```
function render(data) {

  data.forEach(function(currentItem) {
    console.log(currentItem);
  });

}
```

You will find a working example at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZEpqo?editors=001 where you can use an in-browser console (e.g. Chrome Developer Tools) to view the printed output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome that helped a lot. I am just still so new,even with passing things like parameters to functions. But it makes total sense. Calling the Storelistitems function with the args(listItemArray, key) that way when I add task it adds that input to the array.  Also the forEach anonymous function makes more sense without all the random parameters in it. I understand the current parameter refers to the current array, and then logging the contents of it. Awesome thanks! I actually understand your changes :)!

Comment: How can I render what i log to the actual page though on refresh? Using your method?